# How do I see the last command issued in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I issued a query and got results at the `mysql>` command line.

Is there any way (other than edit) that I can see what the last query was?

I vaguely remember that in Oracle pl/sql you could just type `list` but that command isn't available (syntax error) in mysql

Comment: Not sure if I'll state the obvious: pressing "cursor up"? If that is not what you are looking for: do you have admin rights/access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
Additionally, for those blessed with MySQL >= 5.1.12:

Execute SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
Execute SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
Take a look at the table mysql.general_log
If you prefer to output to a file:

SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE"; which is set by default.
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "/path/to/your/logfile.log";
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
I prefer this method because:

you're not editing the my.cnf file and potentially permanently turning on logging
you're not fishing around the filesystem looking for the query log - or even worse, distracted by the need for the perfect destination.  /var/log /var/data/log /opt /home/mysql_savior/var
restarting the server leaves you where you started (log is off)
For more information, see
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log